# Bluetooth Low Energy Device In WPF

Tags: wpf, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to create a desktop app using Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) and WPF. As per my research Microsoft BLE API' not available for WPF.Microsoft has rich UWP APIs for UWP. So can we use UWP BLE APIS on WPF?
I have tried using the Windows Run time component but not a bit of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` API are DualApiPartitioned and it means the API is allowed to be called from desktop apps. So when you want to use BLE APIs, you can try to add the following references in you WPF.

```
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
Windows, in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD​
Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd​
Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\8.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
```

About more detail information, you can read this [link](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#bhpy4thd3s4vfH5u.97).